# java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String resolveWidgetVar(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, intellij-idea

I want to use `primefaces 5` in `intelliJ IDEA`.

I got this exception:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils with signature: java.lang.String resolveWidgetVar(java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processFunctions(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:642)
...
```

I have been added `primefaces5` in maven dependencies, and now is in `WEB-INF/lib` directory:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should ensure that not conflicting versions of PrimeFaces lib in project / target / project / WEB-INF / lib folder. If so then try `mvn:clean` project or `mvn:update`.

Comment: I don't have `/ target / project / WEB-INF / lib ` path. I have /target/classes` or` /target/generated sources` .

Comment: In web project you don't have WEB-INF folder?

Comment: I have `WEB-INF` but the is no `lib` directory under `WEB-INF`.

Comment: You said "I have been added primefaces5 in maven dependencies, and now is in WEB-INF/lib directory"

Comment: Yes, in this path: `web\WEB-INF\lib` not in `\target\project \WEB-INF \lib` path as you say in your first removed comment.

Comment: You don't have target folder?

Comment: In where? `target` folder just presents in root directory and contains two folders named `classes` and `generated-sources` , nothing more.

Comment: This answer does not fix the problem.
I have the same problem and it doesnt work for me neither.

Comment: Sometimes an extra jar from an old dependency can remain in the built war/ear libs. `mvn clean` or IDEA's `Build -> Build Artifacts... -> x -> Clean` will fix it.